# cut a DataFrame und get the minus value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and I need to cut it und get the min from the minus values:

Than I need to export the local min value as array like min_lokal = [-1.3, -2, .....]
and another qustion please: how I git the price with the min_lokal ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ijs7.png)

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [4, 5, -0.8,-1.3, -0.7, -.5, .4, 5, -.9, -.6, -2]})
```

Comment: Please don't change the title/text to incorrect spelling. Also, don't post the images, post the input data and expected output as text.

Comment: Please list the things you have tried regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) with groups created by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
m = df['col'].gt(0)
out = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())['col'].min().tolist()
print (out)
[-1.3, -2.0]
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [1,2,3,5,6,8,7,1,2,3,4],
                   'min_lokal': [4, 5, -0.8,-1.3, -0.7, -.5, .4, 5, -.9, -.6, -2]})
print (df)
    price  min_lokal
0       1        4.0
1       2        5.0
2       3       -0.8
3       5       -1.3
4       6       -0.7
5       8       -0.5
6       7        0.4
7       1        5.0
8       2       -0.9
9       3       -0.6
10      4       -2.0


m = df['min_lokal'].gt(0)
out = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())['min_lokal'].agg(['min','idxmin'])
print (out)
           min  idxmin
min_lokal             
2         -1.3       3
4         -2.0      10

print (out['min'].tolist())
[-1.3, -2.0]

print (df.loc[out['idxmin'], 'price'].tolist())
[5, 4]
```

Comment: That was useful, thanks. And I have another qustion please: how I git the price with the min_loka value. i had a upload another screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ijs7.png

Comment: @Toma - Can you check edited answer?